# How do I install v8@3.15 on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, docker, ruby, gem

I am new to Linux and I am trying to setup a ruby on rails app from work. Now, the Gemfile wants to install therubyracer.

Upon running `bundle install`, it fails:

```
Fetching therubyracer 0.12.3
Installing therubyracer 0.12.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/ext/v8
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20220613-666-1d8cum5.rb extconf.rb --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
checking for -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version 
(Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with 
the libv8 rubygem. 

However, your system version of v8 could not be located. 

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible 
with 3.16.14.19 installed. You may need to use the 
--with-v8-dir option if it is installed in a non-standard location
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
    from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/aarch64-linux/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/aarch64-linux/2.5.0/therubyracer-0.12.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

As it can be seen `checking for v8.h... no`, it is unable to find `v8.h` file. This is because it depends on v8 engine and I am not sure how to install it on Ubuntu:18.04.

I am trying to do this setup with a Dockerfile.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y git curl libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev autoconf bison build-essential libyaml-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm-dev libpq-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python software-properties-common
RUN apt update
RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/HEAD/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git
ENV PATH="/root/.rbenv/bin:${PATH}"
RUN rbenv install 2.5.8
ENV PATH="/root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.8/bin:${PATH}"
RUN eval "$(rbenv init -)"

RUN gem install bundler:1.17.3
RUN bundle config build.therubyracer --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
RUN bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8


COPY . /opt/myapp
WORKDIR /opt/myapp

# RUN bundle install

ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Upon running `docker exec -it my_image`, and then `bundle install`, I get the above error.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
ruby "2.5.8"

gem "oj"

gem "coffee-rails", "~> 4.2"
gem "loofah", "~> 2.9.0"
gem "puma", "~> 5.6.4"
gem "rails", "~> 5.2.7"
gem "rails-html-sanitizer", "~> 1.0.4"
gem "sass-rails", "~> 5.1.0"
gem "turbolinks", "~> 5"
gem "uglifier", ">= 1.3.0"

gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"
gem "execjs"
gem "jsonapi-serializers"
gem "jwt"
gem "newrelic_rpm", "~> 6.12", ">= 6.12.0.367"
gem "rack-cors", "~> 1.0.4", require: "rack/cors"
gem "redis"
gem "redis-mutex"
gem "redis-rails"
gem "simple_command"
gem "therubyracer"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.1.7"

# yanked v0.3.5
gem "mimemagic", github: "mimemagicrb/mimemagic", ref: "01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f"

gem "activeadmin_json_editor", "~> 0.0.7"
gem "awesome_print"
gem "aws-sdk-cloudwatch"
gem "aws-sdk-sqs"
gem "capistrano-sidekiq", group: :development
gem "committee"
gem "config"
gem "dotenv-rails"
gem "foreman"
gem "geocoder", "~> 1.6.1"
gem "high_voltage"
gem "http", "~> 5.0.1"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "leaderboard"
gem "materialize-sass"
gem "memory_profiler"
gem "oink", "~> 0.10.1"
gem "pg", "~> 0.20"
gem "rspec-core", "~> 3.7.1"
gem "rswag"
gem "rubocop", "~> 0.81", require: false
gem "rubocop-performance", "~> 1.5.2", require: false
gem "rubocop-rails", "~> 2.4.2", require: false
gem "sidekiq", "5.2.10"
gem "sidekiq-scheduler"
gem "strong_migrations"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]

# for ether scan address formatting
gem "digest-sha3"
gem "rlp"

group :development, :test do
  gem "byebug", platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.13"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end

group :development do
  gem "letter_opener", "1.6.0"
  gem "listen", ">= 3.0.5", "< 3.2"
  gem "spring"
  gem "spring-watcher-listen", "~> 2.0.0"
  gem "web-console", ">= 3.3.0"
end

group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "capistrano"
  gem "capistrano-bundler"
  gem "capistrano-passenger", ">= 0.1.1"
  gem "capistrano-rails"
  gem "capistrano-rvm"
  gem "guard-bundler"
  gem "guard-rails"
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem "rails_layout"
  gem "rb-fchange", require: false
  gem "rb-fsevent", require: false
  gem "rb-inotify", require: false
  gem "rb-readline"
  gem "spring-commands-rspec"
end
group :development, :test do
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem "faker"
  gem "pry"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "webmock", "~> 3.13.0"
end
group :test do
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "launchy"
  gem "rails-controller-testing"
  gem "rspec-sidekiq"
  gem "shoulda-matchers"
  gem "simplecov", "~> 0.17.1", require: false
end
gem "pusher"

gem "activeadmin", "~> 2.9.0"
gem "activeadmin_addons", "~> 1.7.1"
gem "active_admin_role", "~> 0.2.2"
gem "audited", "~> 4.10.0"
gem "carrierwave", "~> 1.3.2"
gem "devise", "~> 4.7.1"
gem "fog-aws", "~> 3.3.0"
gem "mini_magick"
gem "pg_search", "~> 2.3", ">= 2.3.2"
gem "rotp"
gem "tinymce-rails"

# dynamodb
gem "dynamoid"

gem "activerecord-import", "~> 1.0.1"
gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem "bundler-audit", "~> 0.7.0.1"
gem "device_detector"
gem "karafka"
gem "phonelib", "~> 0.6.44"
gem "sentry-rails"
gem "slack-notifier"

group :development do
  gem "brakeman", "~> 4.10.0"
  gem "bullet"
end

group :development, :test, :staging do
  gem "active_record_query_trace"
end

# parallel rspec
gem "parallel_tests", group: %i[development test]

# cloudflare
gem "cloudflare-rails", "~> 2.0.0", group: %i[production staging testing]

gem "makara", "~> 0.5.1"

gem "distribute_reads", "~> 0.3.4"
gem "multiverse", "~> 0.2.2"
gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.12.5"

gem "elastic-apm", group: %i[production staging]

gem "ddtrace", require: "ddtrace/auto_instrument"

gem "rails_semantic_logger"
```

Can someone help me get through this? Help me understand how I can install v8 engine with Docker? I tried `apt install libv8-dev`. apt is unable to find libv8-dev.

I can install v8@3.15 on mac using brew: `brew install v8@3.15`.

How can I install v8@3.15 on ubuntu docker?